# Apexcharts, how do I find positional value for the highest and lowest marker on the line, so i can add an image to that one specific marker?

Tags: apexcharts

I would like to add arrows to the chart, I am guessing if i can find the position of the highest marker, I can use it to add some html to get some custom tool-tips or markers.
I tried looking for a format[image] function in markers, and in the axis, I just am not sure what I am looking for here.
Any help is much appreciated. I haven't been able to wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 3):

The feature is a WIP and I am in the process of creating examples to illustrate the functionality.

The proposed API for the feature will look like below

```
 var options = {
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: "area",
    events: {
      mounted: function(ctx, config) {
        const lowest = ctx.getLowestValueInSeries(0)
        const highest = ctx.getHighestValueInSeries(0)

        ctx.addPointAnnotation({
          x: new Date(ctx.w.globals.seriesX[0][ctx.w.globals.series[0].indexOf(lowest)]).getTime(),
          y: lowest,
          label: {
            text: 'Lowest: ' + lowest,
            offsetY: 2
          },
          customSVG: {
              SVG: `<path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"/>
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>`,
              cssClass: undefined,
              offsetX: -10,
              offsetY: -30
          }
        })

        ctx.addPointAnnotation({
          x: new Date(ctx.w.globals.seriesX[0][ctx.w.globals.series[0].indexOf(highest)]).getTime(),
          y: highest,
          label: {
            text: 'Highest: ' + highest,
            offsetY: 2
          },
        })
      }
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}
```

which will produce the following result
[image: Highest/Lowest points]

The functionality is not available in the current release (3.5.1) of ApexCharts, but it will soon be added in 3.6.0 which is going to be released this weekend (March 10, 2019).

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of ApexCharts*

Comment: Yes, it will. Instead of calling the above functions after chart.render(), you will call it in the 'mounted' event of ApexCharts. I will provide an example for it on the website.

Comment: Released 3.6.0. Also updated the above answer so it is easier to integrate into React/Vue code.